# Custom enpoint dont work in Keycloak v 21.1.2

Tags: jax-rs, keycloak, quarkus, keycloak-services, keycloak-rest-api

How to make custom endpoints for a keyclock? I did as in this project from the Key clock developers: https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/tree/main/examples/providers/rest

Then I put the jar in the keycloak docker container in the /opt/keycloak/providers directory, build it  and tried to open the endpoint http://localhost:8080/realms/master/hello

However, the error "Uncaught server error: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.InternalServerErrorException: RESTEASY003815: Subresource for target class has no jax-rs annotations.: org.keycloak.examples.rest.HelloResourceProvider"

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: If you use the latestest Version, the problem may be that Version 22 uses a different rest Version. Try to run it with keycloak 22 if possible otherwise checkout an older version of the example